# How to check CheckListBox item with single click?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I am coding Windows `Forms` application in C# and using `CheckListBox` Control.

**How to check CheckListBox item with just single click?**

Answer (score 188, accepted):

I think you are looking for

**[CheckOnClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkonclick.aspx)** property

set it to true

> Gets or sets a value indicating
>   whether the check box should be
>   toggled when an item is selected.

Comment: You can find this in the properties window of the checkedlistbox control.

Answer (score 11):

Set the property at Design Time in this way

[image]

or by code:

```
CheckedListBox.CheckOnClick = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

I just finished working through an issue where I had set CheckOnClick to True via the designer, but the UI was still requiring a second click to check items. What I found is that for whatever reason, the designer file was not updating when I changed the value.  To resolve, I went into the designer file and added a line

```
this.Product_Group_CheckedListBox.CheckOnClick = true;
```

After this, it worked as expected.  Not sure why the designer didn't update, but maybe this workaround will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a check box exterior to the CheckListBox to check/uncheck all items.  On the same form add a checkbox near the CheckedListBox and name it CkCheckAll.  Add the Click event for the CheckBox (which I prefer to the CheckChanged event).
There is also a button (BtnAdd) next to the CheckedListBox which will add all checked items to a database table.  It is only enabled when at least one item in the CheckedListBox is checked.

```
    private void CkCheckAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CkCheckAll.Text = (CkCheckAll.Checked ? "Uncheck All" : "Check All");
        int num = Cklst_List.Items.Count;
        if (num > 0)
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                Cklst_List.SetItemChecked(i, CkCheckAll.Checked);
            }
        }
        BtnAdd_Delete.Enabled = (Cklst_List.CheckedItems.Count > 0) ? true : false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also check all by button click or click on checklist

```
private void checkedListBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);

}
```

Comment: How can you do this using a foreach statement?

Comment: @Bryan try this and body of loop cast the object into check list 
foreach (Object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)

Comment: Using the count command in a loop should be avoided. As the name of the command states. The count uses time to count the item in the list in each iteration of the loop. If the list only supports a count use:
int totalitems = checkedListBox1.Count;
Then use variable in the for loop.